# Refresh Flutter ListView after OnTap

Tags: listview, flutter

I want to change the view of a selected item *(_itemSelected)*. It works when I select an item but the other items doesn't refresh. There is something like notifydatasetchanged? Something I missed? Thanks!

```
class MyItemListItem extends State<MyItemList> {
  final MyItem item;

  MyItemListItem(this.item);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListTile(
        key: _itemListItem,
        onTap: () {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
              content: new Text("You clicked item number " + item.name)));
          _itemSelected = item;

          setState(() {

          });
        },
        leading: new CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        title: _itemSelected != null && item == _itemSelected
            ? new Row(children: <Widget>[new Text("Foo"), new Text("Bar")])
            : new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(child: new Text(item.name)),
                ],
              ));
  }
}
```

Comment: "something like notifydatasetchanged" `setState` does that. You probable need to call that on the parent widget (the one that contains the ListView).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I called _scaffoldKey.currentState.setState((){}); with no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out the problem.
Like Günter Zöchbauer suggested I added

```
_scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
              content: new Text("You clicked item number " + item.name)));
          _itemSelected = item;

          home.addItem();

        },
```

where home is the parent widget.

```
void addItem() {
    setState(() {

    });
  }
```